# Build error in Qt Creator in release but not in debug

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm working with Qt 5.15.2 in Qt Creator 6.0.2.
I have a program that uses a .lib file which was built in both debug (_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL = 0) and release (_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL = 2) versions. I can build the debug version of my program with no problems, but when I try to build the release I get this error:

> LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in button.obj

I also get

> LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' doesn't match value 'MD_DyamicRelease' in button.obj

I understand my .obj files are somehow linked to ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL = 0 and MDd, but I don't know how to change these parameters on the Qt project.

### Update

Here's the .pro file:

```
QT += core gui qml
QT += serialport
QT += multimedia

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11
CONFIG += console


#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000

SOURCES += \
    button.cpp \
    checkbox.cpp \
    combolist.cpp \
    controlpanel.cpp \
    expressionevaluator.cpp \
    filter.cpp \
    globals.cpp \
    logicaloperator.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp \
    neurobit.cpp \
    numericdisplay.cpp \
    oscilloscope.cpp \
    pnwiz.cpp \
    pnwiz_devicethread.cpp \
    pnwiz_ui.cpp \
    pnwizconfigwindow.cpp \
    pnwizconnectionmenu.cpp \
    pnwizelectrocapmenu.cpp \
    score.cpp \
    shadow.cpp \
    shadowpanel.cpp \
    shadowvolume.cpp \
    shadowwindow.cpp \
    threshold.cpp \
    thresholdbar.cpp \
    timetransform.cpp \
    variablefilter.cpp

HEADERS += \
    button.h \
    checkbox.h \
    combolist.h \
    controlpanel.h \
    expressionevaluator.h \
    filter.h \
    globals.h \
    logicaloperator.h \
    mainwindow.h \
    neurobit.h \
    numericdisplay.h \
    oscilloscope.h \
    pnwiz.h \
    pnwiz_devicethread.h \
    pnwiz_ui.h \
    pnwizconfigwindow.h \
    pnwizconnectionmenu.h \
    pnwizelectrocapmenu.h \
    score.h \
    shadow.h \
    shadowpanel.h \
    shadowvolume.h \
    shadowwindow.h \
    threshold.h \
    thresholdbar.h \
    timetransform.h \
    variablefilter.h

FORMS += \
    button.ui \
    checkbox.ui \
    combolist.ui \
    controlpanel.ui \
    mainwindow.ui \
    numericdisplay.ui \
    pnwiz_ui.ui \
    pnwizconfigwindow.ui \
    pnwizconnectionmenu.ui \
    pnwizelectrocapmenu.ui \
    shadowpanel.ui \
    shadowwindow.ui \
    threshold.ui \
    thresholdbar.ui \
    variablefilter.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

RESOURCES += \
    Images.qrc \
    Sounds.qrc

LIBS += -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lodbc32 -lodbccp32


unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../Filtros01/Filtros01-Output/Products/x64Debug/ -lDSPFilters

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/DSPFilters_original/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/DSPFilters_original/include
```

And here's the qmake call:

```
E:/Qt/5.15.2/msvc2019_64/bin/qmake.exe E:\C++\Qt\QWiz_4\QWiz_4.pro -spec win32-msvc "CONFIG+=qtquickcompiler" && E:/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/jom/jom.exe qmake_all
```

### Update 2

I tried the solution proposed by Evgene and now I get a different error message:

> LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in button.obj

Any ideas on how this can be corrected?

### Update 3

Ok, I was able to solve it by releasing the library in MD mode.
Now I can build in release mode. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are probably still linking against the debug libraries, even in release, instead of the proper release libraries. How are you compiling? Are you using qmake? If so, show the related file(s).

Comment: Yes, I'm using qmake. Which files do you need me to show?

Comment: The `.pro` file (and anything else that's relevant to the qmake process)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../Filtros01/Filtros01-Output/Products/x64Debug/ -lDSPFilters
```

As you can see, you always use `x64Debug` libs build.
Try something like this

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../Filtros01/Filtros01-Output/Products/x64Debug/
}
else {
   unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../Filtros01/Filtros01-Output/Products/x64Release/
}
unix|win32: LIBS += -lDSPFilters
```

Of course make sure the `x64Release` path exists and replace it if needed.